# Navigating to specific place in the document with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

First I want to point that I have tried to solve my issue with NGRX but I know it was the wrong solution and it yielded some other issues with the usage of Angular.

I have one page web app built in Angular separated to number of sections instead of separated pages.
The app also has a navigation bar which contain buttons to navigate to selected section in the **same page** (instead of "route" to other page).

The point is that each section has no fixed height, since it depends on it's inside content => **Height = dynamic number**.

In order to provide the offset which *scrollTo* function needs to receive, I need to make a cross component communication between my **navbar.component.ts** to unlimited number of components (number of sections which could be edited).

If I will use a service, it means that I will need to check which component (with the section inside) needs to be checked (for height) - Which I also not sure how to do.

Appreciate any assistance with this.

Thanks!

**____________________________________________________________________**

**My NGRX solution:** (You can skip this paragraph as it just describes the solution I've tried)

As mentioned above, I tried to use NGRX for that, by storing each section's height in my NGRX store and retrieve it when using the navigation buttons.

I did it since I am already storing the menu items data (URL #fragment name, display name, etc...) in my NGRX store, so I just added an **offset**.

I used **.dispatch** for storing the offset on two cases:

1. When page is resized (as the heights of the DOMs could be changed)
     @HostListener("window:resize", [])
2. When the view is initialized
     ngAfterViewInit()

**This presented the following error:** ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

[image: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError]
I have read a little and understood that this could be solved by wrapping the changes (dispatch) in the store in "setTimeout" method, but it comes with performance issues (Re-rendering the entire app - which I don't want to do).

**Why is this error occurred if I'm only changing data and not some DOM?**

The thing is - I am changing the DOM! that's because I'm changing some data in the store, and it's "refresh" all my store data which part of it used for rendering the DOM (for example - **navbar button display name** - which I mentioned before).
**____________________________________________________________________**

UPDATE:

I have tried to wrap everying whitin zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {}) (Following this great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsBy9O0c6eo)
within the ngAfterViewInit() but it still shows me the same error.

[image: new method]

Comment: https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/ and
https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10

Comment: @timdeschryver Thank you. I've tried to use the method suggested (description added above) and still get the same error